# Formulário de cadastro personalizado com angularjs + Meteor

Tags: angularjs, formulário, meteor

eu estou aprendendo recentemente AngularJS + Meteor, e estou fazendo esse tutorial:

http://www.angular-meteor.com/tutorials/socially/angular1/user-accounts-authentication-and-permissions

Nesse exato passo, estou tendo problemas em customizar o formulário de cadastro.

O cadastro que é sugerido se transforma na diretiva  com simplesmente um email e senha, com um layout padrão. É completamente impossivel eu utilizar esse design e essa pobreza de inputs na minha aplicação real (que estou fazendo usando as bases do tutorial).

Eu preciso dar classes pros inputs para personalizar, e preciso adicionar os inputs na collection users (usando o accounts-password), como faço isso? A documentação ensina como adicionar usando METEOR, mas como faço usando Meteor + angular?

PReciso dos campos: Email, nome completo, celular, data de nascimento, etc etc, o html desses campos eu sei fazer, com seus inputs, mas como jogar esses inputs na collection user? (usando o package accounts-password)

http://docs.meteor.com/api/passwords.html#Accounts-createUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale lembrar que se

```
Accounts.createUser(novoUser); //
```

For feito em uma pasta client, o novo user será salvo e o login será feito automaticamente, já se ele for salvo em um arquivo no server, o novoUser será apenas salvo na collection

Comment: Boa iniciativa o complemento, pode editar sua resposta, e adicionar o complemento.

Comment: Muito obrigado!!! Não sabia disso, realmente ele faz login automático

Answer (score 2):

Quando se trata da Collection "users" o Meteor oferece um schema especial que contem campos default como
password, username, emails(um array de emails), createAt, service e PROFILE(que é o que você procura). 
No objeto profile voce pode acrescentar dados de sua vontade como nome, idade etc.
No link da documentação do Meteor você encontrará mais detalhes:

http://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-users

Basta definir um 'novoUser' no seu controller, por exemplo.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.novoUser.profile.nome">
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.novoUser.profile.idade">
<input type="text" ng-model="$ctrl.novoUser.password">


Accounts.createUser(novoUser); //no seu método salvar
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo! Sua resposta foi bem concisa e didática, espero que ajude tambem outras pessoas!